# Unable to integrate Calendar Lib in my project

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

From last 3 days, I am struggling to use calendar lib in my code. I got the example project but no luck in running it. I studied the code and try by creating simple project. 
I managed to link Calendar lib but can not insert event yet. Can anyone guide me how to insert event in calendar view?

My purpose of using this lib is only to show events. I am trying to insert event starting from current date-time to tomorrow date-time. For that I use:

```
MGCDateRange* dateRange = [[MGCDateRange alloc]initWithStart:[NSDate date] end:newDate1];
[self.weekViewController.dayPlannerView insertEventOfType:MGCAllDayEventType withDateRange:dateRange];
```

But got error as:

> 2016-09-07 13:44:09.781 CalenderLibExample[2203:92344] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'attempt to insert item 0 into section 0, but there are only 0
>   items in section 0 after the update'

Comment: You can format your code by indenting each line with 4 spaces. I recommend you do the same thing for your errors too. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: I got where the error is but not getting the solution to fix.

Comment: Your question is poorly formatted. Please edit it so that people can read it. If it's a mess, nobody will want to help you.

Comment: I am also using calendar lib in my project for showing time-line but getting same sort of issues

Comment: Is it in proper format now?

Comment: And what is `self.weekViewController.dayPlannerView`? The error is explicitly, I don't know what's the object, but it seems to be a typical error of UICollectionView/UITableView when the dataSource has to reflect the changes (number of items in sections, number of sections, etc.)

Comment: Yes, its related to UICollectionView. I have searched about the issue and got if the cell is not loaded it throw such error. So I scroll to the specific date. But again no luck in scrolling. I am unable to properly use Calendar Lib's methods.

Comment: Anyone who have used this library please guide. https://github.com/jumartin/Calendar